# What is this replacement doing?

Tags: perl

```
$_ =~ s/\#N\/A//g;
```

it's replacing \3N\ with A\ are these special characters in perl?  Sorry I have no idea how to look up this syntax even.

Comment: It's a perl regular expression. Try http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html for more details of perl's regexes. Also, a google of 'perl operator =~' could have give you some clues.

Comment: @MichaelKohne, Google will silently ignore the `=~` part.

Comment: @doubleDown - Interesting. Don't know why I got perlre as my first hit earlier. Now I get perlop, which tells what the =~ operator is, and references perlre. So it works either way.

Answer (score 5):

It is removing #N/A from the string `$_`.

`\#N` matches `#N` (escaping the `#`)

`\/A` matches `/A` (escaping the `/`)

You can simplify how confusing this looks by changing the substitution delimiter:

```
$_ =~ s|#N/A||g;
```

Answer (score 3):

Like Hunter McMillen said, It is removing `#N/A` from the default variable.

But you can code something more readable and shorter :

```
s!#N/A!!g;
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Hunter McMillen mentioned, it's just normal regex substitution with special characters escaped. It's probably better written as

```
s|#N/A||g
```

or

```
s{#N/A}{}g
```

Answer (score 0):

In Damian Conway's *Perl Best Practices*, to make regular expressions more readable, he recommends:

```
s{ \# N \/ A }{}gmsx;
```

That is:

1. Use curly braces around the pattern and replacement.
2. Use spaces to separate parts of the pattern via the /x switch.
3. Backslash escape non-alphanumeric characters, even if they aren't meta-characters.